# Why can't i run Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS Headless?

Tags: server, grub2, debian

I have done a fresh install with Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS. As soon as i remove the GPU and reboot.I am unable to ssh into the computer. I am able to run Truenas and Unraid headless. So it does not seem to be a motherboard limitation. Ubuntu Server only works headless if i remove the GPU after the OS have started. It is a headache and probably unsafe to do that after each boot.

I have tried editing Grub with nomodeset in default with a grub-update afterwards. But that does not seem to solve it. I am loss for words so far. Why do people use this if you can't run it as a headless server? Is there something missing in the documentation?

Comment: did you see [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs) and does it help?

Comment: What is your target CPU/systemboard and GPU type?

Comment: Hardware: Steel legend b550m and r5 3600  with 32gb ecc ram. Since yesterday i have tested archlinux and fedora. They work headless without any changes. But i can't get debian and ubuntu server to work headless. I really want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having the same problem . I added GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=1 but doesn't work.